# Finch: how can i define Endpoint with param in the middle

Tags: scala, rest, finagle, finch

i am trying to define an Endpoint with param in the middle.

something similar to:

**get("foo" :: param("id") :: "goo")**

so, i can call it with the following rest call:

**http://mydomain/foo?id=99/goo**

but, for some reason, it doesn't work.

any idea ?

thanks,
Eran.

Comment: It does not work because it is not a valid url pattern. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL for more information. Things after `?` such as `?abc=11&xyz=ijk` are called query parameters and can appear only at the end of an URL.

Answer (score 0):

In your `get("foo" :: param("id") :: "goo")` handler, this `"foo" :: param("id") :: "goo"` is is called `route path`.

And this `param("id")` is actually a `path-parameter` and not a `query-parameter`.

Standard URL scheme looks like following,

```
scheme:[//[user[:password]@]host[:port]][/path][?query][#fragment]
```

`path-parameters` are actually not part of standard `URL scheme` but are extracted from `path` part of URL using regular expression matching by modern http frameworks.

So... you need to access it with http url - `http://mydomain/foo/99/goo`